# I am trying to fetch calendars from outlook using a python script. I am getting an invalid scope value error. What am I missing?

Tags: python, authentication, outlook

I am trying to use a Python script to fetch my shared calendars in outlook. I am a first year computer science major and beginner. I thought it would be nice to have all my calendar events print to the terminal and I thought this little activity would benefit me. However, I get an invalid scope value error in my browser, after pasting the sign-in portal link into chrome. I have added all the permissions and platform configs to Azure that I thought I needed to? What am I missing?

Error in browser:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/nativeclient?error=invalid_scope&error_description=The%20provided%20value%20for%20the%20input%20parameter%20%27scope%27%20is%20not%20valid.%20The%20scope%20%27Calendars.Read.Shared%27%20is%20not%20valid.&state=iC6gDfcX1C7BCPfsrvdHpp4a7kzcRr
```

Terminal Output:

```
Visit the following url to give consent:
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=844ecf49-96c1-422d-a611-b7bad4882745&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flogin.microsoftonline.com%2Fcommon%2Foauth2%2Fnativeclient&scope=Calendars.Read.Shared&state=iC6gDfcX1C7BCPfsrvdHpp4a7kzcRr&access_type=offline
Paste the authenticated url here:
```

Here's my code:

```
from O365 import Account, MSGraphProtocol

CLIENT_ID = '844ecf49-96c1-422d-a611-b7bad4882745'
SECRET_ID = 'q~-n~w9_kTb6mTIrbmcA2-139rqiSph4n_'
SCOPE = ["Calendars.Read.Shared"]

credentials = (CLIENT_ID, SECRET_ID)

protocol = MSGraphProtocol()

account = Account(credentials, protocol=protocol)

if account.authenticate(scopes=SCOPE):
    print("Authenticated!")

schedule = account.schedule()
calendar = schedule.get_default_calendar()
events = calendar.get_events(include_recurring=False)

for event in events:
    print(event)
```

[permissions in Azure image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tynyy.png)

[Platform configurations in Azure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lU89a.png)